# How to store a jwt token with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, backend, token

I have a token that comes from another API and I need to save this token so I can use it elsewhere in my application, how can I do that? Is there any way to use this token outside of then ?

This is a backend application with nodejs.

```
await axios.post(URL).then((response) => {
        let token = response.data.access_token)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(404).json(err)
    })
```

Comment: but it's in the backend of this application that I'm doing, is there a way to use localstorage in the backend with nodejs?

Comment: You can store in db.

Comment: I managed to solve it, I found a library called node-localstorage, and now I can store my token, and use it in any part of my application in the backend

Comment: Great, thank for that `node-localstorage`, pkg. Will check that.  By the way instead of that package, can you add that the token to `globals`, this will keep that token in your app till next server start.

Comment: see this, it can help : https://www.cyberchief.ai/2023/05/secure-jwt-token-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, I found a library called node-localstorage, and now I can store my token, and use it in any part of my application in the backend

```
const LocalStorage = require('node-localstorage').LocalStorage('./scratch'); 

await axios.post(URL).then((response) => {
        LocalStorage.setItem('TOKEN', `Bearer ${response.data.access_token}`) 
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(404).json(err)
    })
```